# FeathersJS: How to cancel the authentication hook using an error from a hook after it

Tags: promise, async-await, feathersjs, feathers-authentication, feathers-hook

I used `app.authenticate` on client. 
It called the authentication hook in before create hook on server.
I imported from 'feathers-authentication-manage.hook' as `verifyHooks`.

Before create hook:

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),
        async context => {
          const { app, data } = context;

          await app.service('users').find({
            query: {
              usernameUpperCase: data.username.toUpperCase(),
              $limit: 1
            }
          })
          .then(async (user) => {
            await user.data.map(async data => {
              if(!data.isVerified) {
                await console.log('HELLO FROM ABOVE.');
                //await v.validationError('Verify Email. A token link has been sent to your email.');
              }
            });
          })
          .catch(err => v.validationError(err));
        },
        verifyHooks.isVerified()
      ],
```

The 3 hooks in order were:
1. authentication
2. my hook
3. `isVerified()` email verify hook from feathers-authentication management

On client, the authenticate promise would be rejected when `isVerified()` hook activated even if was after the authentication hook.
If I removed the `isVerified()` hook, the authenticate promise would resolve.

How do I make my hook, the second hook, behave like `isVerified()` so the authenticate promise on client be rejected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is that you are making your life harder by using `async/await` not as it is intended. The idea is to not having to write all those `.then` and `.catch` handlers.

The `.catch` handler is also probably where actual issue is. If a `.catch` (in your case `v.validationError(err)`) does not reject or throw an error, the promise will resolve successfully. Using `async/await` the right way and `Promise.all` to wait for the asynchronous validation steps and then re-throwing the validation error should do it:

```
app.service('authentication').hooks({
    before: {
      create: [
        authentication.hooks.authenticate(config.strategies),
        async context => {
          const { app, data } = context;

          const user = await app.service('users').find({
            query: {
              usernameUpperCase: data.username.toUpperCase(),
              $limit: 1
            }
          });

          try {
            await Promise.all(user.data.map(async data => {
              if(!data.isVerified) {
                await console.log('HELLO FROM ABOVE.');
                //await v.validationError('Verify Email. A token link has been sent to your email.');
              }
            });
          } catch(err) {
            throw v.validationError(err);
          }
        },
```

Comment: You were correct. I did not use async/await correctly. Your code worked. I also removed all the async/await inside the then() for mine to work.